Model properties modified on server side failed to display the modified values in a View
I am facing a rather strange issue. I am new to Asp.Net Core so perhaps I have done something really stupid.  Below is a simplification of my project to explain the issue:
my code
more code
When I open the view, I get the message "Amount is not 150000" as I expect.  However, when I hit the Save button, I expect the Amount control to display the 150000 set in the controller but it is not working.  The view displays the input element but with 0.00; the default value.  The fact that it displays the control means the model property Amount returns with a value of 150000.  What is perplexing to me is why it does not display it!
Anyone faced anything like this?  This problem started after I ran another training Blazor project where I had to enable interactive rendering.  I don't expect the settings in the Blazor project to affect the settings in the Asp.Net Core project!
I have tried explicitly using @Model.Disbursement.Amount but it has not worked.
I have inspected the page after the post and it is showing value of 0.00 for the Amount element. Element name is Disbursement.Amount and id is Disbursement_Amount.  I dont see any naming conflict.

.NET Core MVC uses combination of model and ModelState values for displaying data in the views. ModelState values seem to override what is inside the model.
I had that issue too and wasn't able to find any official documentation about it from Microsoft.
So here is what you can try although it's not ideal:
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Create(DisbursmentVM vm)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        vm.DisbursmentAmount = 15000;
        ModelState.Clear(); // Add this to reset model state values.
    }

    return View(vm);
}

Another perhaps cleaner way would be to redirect to GET action from your POST action:
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Create(DisbursmentVM vm)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Create), new { disbursmentAmount = 15000 });
    }

    return View(vm);
}

public IActionResult Create([FromQuery] decimal disbursmentAmount)
{
     return View(new DisbursmentVM
     {
         DisbursmentAmount = disbursmentAmount
     });
}


Thanks a lot for this answer! I used the ModelState.Clear() and it solved the issue.  I will also try out the second option. Great!
